# Can use of HtmlAgilityPack be modified to only extract main part of HTML document?

Tags: html, .net, html-agility-pack, text-extraction, document-body

I have some .NET code that ingests HTML files and extracts text from them. I am using `HtmlAgilityPack` to do the extraction. Before I wanted to extract most of the text that was there that was there, so it worked fine. Now requirements have changed and I need to only extract text from he main body of the document. So suppose I scraped HTML from a news webpage. I just want the text of the article, not the ads, titles of other albeit related articles, header/footers etc.

It is possible to modify my calls to `HtmlAgilityPack` to only extract the main text? Or is there an alternative way to do the extraction?

Here's the current block of code that gets text from HTML:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;  

public string ConvertHtml(string html)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    ConvertTo(doc.DocumentNode, sw);
    sw.Flush();
    return sw.ToString();
}

public void ConvertTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
{
    string html;
    switch (node.NodeType)
    {
    case HtmlNodeType.Comment:
        // don't output comments
        break;

    case HtmlNodeType.Document:
        ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
        break;

    case HtmlNodeType.Text:
        // script and style must not be output
        string parentName = node.ParentNode.Name;
        if ((parentName == "script") || (parentName == "style"))
            break;

        // get text
        html = ((HtmlTextNode) node).Text;

        // is it in fact a special closing node output as text?
        if (HtmlNode.IsOverlappedClosingElement(html))
            break;

        // check the text is meaningful and not a bunch of whitespaces
        if (html.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            outText.Write(HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(html));
        }
        break;

    case HtmlNodeType.Element:
        switch (node.Name)
        {
            case "p":
                // treat paragraphs as crlf
                outText.Write("\r\n");
                break;
        }

        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void ConvertContentTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode subnode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        ConvertTo(subnode, outText);
    }
}
```

So, ideally, what I want is to let `HtmlAgilityPack` determine which parts of the input HTML constitute the "main" text block and input only those elements. I do not know what the structure of input HTML will be but I do know that it will vary a lot (before it was a lot more static)

Comment: Of course this is possible. Use `SelectNodes` to extract only the things you're looking for. If you'd share the code you have now and the HTML you want to extract from plus the stuff you want to extract we can help you.

Comment: OK, I'll add code, but one thing that I did not explain well was that the HTMLs I get vary a lot in the structure and I don't know what this structure is beforehand. I do not want to try parsing HTML first to figure out what nodes to select. Instead, I want to be able to specify something that I want to extract the main block and let `HtmlAgilityPack` or whatever other library I end up suing to figure out what "main" means

Comment: *You* need to figure out what Main means. The HtmlAgilityPack won't be able to make that decision for you. There are some conventions in HTML that indicate the role of a content block, but the sites you're looking for might not implement that.

Comment: You could use the HTML Semantic Elements and grab the `<article>` and `<section>` elements from the document. This requires the content producer to follow this best-practice.